# when string in string pool is created it doesn't allow duplicate, Does it use hashCode to detect whether it is duplicate or not?

Tags: java, hashcode

String object is created using " ", so it is created in String Pool. Does  It uses hashCode to decide whether it is duplicate or not?

```
String s1="abc";
String s2="abc";
```

Comment: That has to work. What says the compiler? The thing is the same variable can't have another value. Not that different variables can't have same value

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you care?

Comment: I am curious why don't you care?

Comment: One might choose not to care because it is an implementation detail. The only important thing is that it has this behaviour, not how exactly it achieves it.

Comment: @PranaySaha: I don't care because I have no reason to care about the low-level, implementation-specific aspects of the string pool. I notice you didn't answer my question about why you think you *do* have reason to care about them. You don't have to, of course, I'm just curious. There are so many other things I'd bother with before the details of the string pool implementation... :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not documented whether it uses `hashCode`. The `intern` mechanism is purely specified in high-level terms, in the JavaDoc for [`String#intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) and v. briefly in the JLS, [§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

This means implementations can do what they want to do, and so they can use the `hashCode` as **part of** determining if the string is already in the pool (it can't be the entire solution, a string's `hashCode` doesn't uniquely identify it; you have to look at its sequence of characters). Oracle's implementation makes `intern` a native method, so one would have to go digging through the JVM code to figure out what it does.

Comment: Completely talking through my hat, but I'd be surprised if the hash code were used. Making an efficient tree for storing unique strings is just as easily done using the string characters themselves, and since it has to check them anyway...

Comment: Yep I know its not full solution but I am just asking about hashcode. I know it also checks using equals method.